# Sencha Touch Flip Animation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, sencha-touch

I have 2 panels (front and back of "card") and when the user swipes up/down I activate the setActiveItem(1, {type:'flip',direction:'down'}); but when the animation plays, it looks like it's spinning or something else... I tried up/down/left/right and nothing appears to make it look like a flip.

Any ideas?

Android 2.3.3 Droid X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just Android. It's known issue. It should be fixed in sencha touch 2. Check this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135798-List-of-Known-Android-Issues-Fixed-in-Upcoming-Release and this http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-what-to-expect/

Comment: Do you know when the release date is for Sencha Touch 2? or is there a dev build yet?

Comment: No dev build yet, but it should be available shortly after the Sencha Conference on October 23rd – 26th.